# How to change compositor getting in parrot os

Tags: parrotsec

I recently installed parrot os. I have screen glitch as soon as I login.

On googling the problem I found this solution:
 https://community.parrotsec.org/t/live-parrotos-screen-tearing-glitch/5671

My problem is I don't know where to change the compositor settings in parrot os.

Answer (score 0):

Have You Found The Solution ? If Not Then Follow Me !

1. Go To Menu
2. Search For Mate Tweak
3. In Mate Tweak Go In Windows
4. You Will Find Windows Manager
5. Click On Select A Window Manager
6. Select Macro(Compton GPU compositor)

Now The Screen Won't Get Glitched Again (It Worked For Me )

And .. Sorry For Bad English !

Have A Great Day !!!

Answer (score 0):

Just solved it! Distorted screen on Parrotsec Os desktop!
Control centre->window preferences-> disable the option”Enable software compositing window manager! And... done!